# Event triggered by event on base class, not derived class

Tags: c#, events

I have the following structure:

```
class item
Static EventHandler Boom

public virtual void handleStuff();

public void DoStuff()
trigger Boom EventHandler
handleStuff(); 

class childItem1 : item
    override handleStuff() etc

class childItem2 : item
    override handleStuff() etc
```

So basicly when I call childItem1.DoStuff(); it will trigger the even on the "Item" class and then execute the handleStuff() on the childItem1 class.

So here's my problem, when I subscribe to the event childItem1.Boom it will also trigger if I call childITem2.Dostuff(); as it also triggers the boom event on the "item" class

So here's the question, how can I defined eventhandlers on a base class, which I can subscribe to on derived classes, but without the above issue?

Comment: Please post the actual code - the pseudo code tells us nothing.

Answer (score 1):

This must be because you have your event declared as `Static`.

If you have an non-static event declared on your base class then the event will be invoked correctly as you expect.

The following program will print `Derived` apprpriately -

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var d = new Derived();
            d.Boom += new EventHandler(HandleBoom);

            d.TriggerBoom();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void HandleBoom(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sender.GetType());
        }
    }

    class Base
    {
        public event EventHandler Boom = null;

        public void TriggerBoom()
        {
            if(Boom != null)
                Boom(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    class Derived : Base
    {
    }
```